# theos,how to use custom class import to tweak.xm

Tags: objective-c, class

when I import custom classes ,it could be complied without warning or errs.But...you know,it just not work.Any idea?

```
#import "./myclass/MyClass.h"

static MyClass* myClass=[%c(MyClass) withState:0];

[myClass getDataFromServer];
```

the  funs

```
- (id)initWithState:(NSUInteger)state
{
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    _stateNow=state;
    _stateToSet=state;
  }
 return self;
}

+ (id)withState:(NSUInteger)state
{
  return [[[self alloc] initWithState:state] autorelease];
}
- (void)getDataFromServer{
UIAlertView* av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"", nil)
                              message:@"Connection fail"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil,
                              nil] ;
av.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 330, 480 );
av.tag=kScreenTag;
    [av show];
}
```

Comment: how does it not work? can you show the entire header and implementation files? also, what is the `%c(MyClass)` syntax? i've never seen it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it sloved.

static MyClass* myClass=[MyClass withState:0];

And makefile should be changed.